# VBA Excel get max value from pivot table

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am trying to grab the max value in a pivot table and display the corresponding row.

For example

Row Label | Sum of Resource

row 1:       22

row 2:       30

row 3"       15

It will display row 2 since 30 is the largest value.

What I have is here

```
Function getMaxPT()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim max As Integer
Dim PTfield As PivotField

Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each PTfield In pt.RowFields
    Debug.Print PTfield.Name
Next PTfield
End Function
```

PS. I am using excel 2010 on windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid a loop and refer to the datarange of the column if only interested in one column (assuming subtotals are off and single column row fields)

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim localMax As Long, myRange As Range, found As Range
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Set pvt = Worksheets("Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set myRange = pvt.PivotFields("Sum of Resource").DataRange
    localMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myRange)
    Set found = myRange.Find(localMax)
    Debug.Print localMax, Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(found.Row, pvt.RowRange.Column)
End Sub
```

---

**Data:**

[image: data]

---

**Results:**

localMax = 19; b   (row = 5)

---

For all columns, not just one, if subtotals and grandtotals are off, use

```
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange
```

For all columns with grand total, but no subtotals:

```
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange
Set myRange = myRange.Resize(myRange.Rows.Count - 1, myRange.Columns.Count)
```

Comment: I want to avoid using ranges if the pivot table changes in size

Comment: The above is dynamic. It will refer to whatever the current size of the pivottable is.

Comment: See [this](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) for background info.

Comment: Ok, but how do I display "b" instead of 5 since that is the row label

Comment: Debug.Print localMax, Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(found.Row, Worksheets("Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowRange.Column)   But you have the variable pvt so just  Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(found.Row, pvt.RowRange.Column)

Comment: I am not sure what happens though if you have compound row labels i.e. more than one item in the row labels. You then need to be more specific.

Comment: I won't have grouped rows so that won't be an issue. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of a specific field, you should loop through its cells. Then make some comparison to take the maximum. This returns the maximal value of all `RowFields` in the PivotTable:

```
Function getMaxPT()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim max As Double
    Dim PTfield As PivotField
    Dim var As Variant

    Set pt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    For Each PTfield In pt.RowFields
        For Each var In PTfield.DataRange.Cells
            If max < var Then max = var
            Debug.Print var
        Next var
    Next PTfield

    MsgBox max

End Function
```

Comment: So does this look for the max in each pivot field? If I wanted to search the max for one pivot field could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just another little implementation of a function to get the max of a specific column on a pivot table, based on previous answers. You can pass the pivot table name and the field name.

```
Function getMaxPT(istrPTName As String, istrPTField As String) As Double
  ' Found the max value in a column from a pivot table
  ' Author: Mauricio Roa, mauricio_roa_f@yahoo.com
  ' Date: 2018-10-02

  Dim myRange As Range
  Dim pt As PivotTable
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim bPTFounded As Boolean

  ' Search for the pivot table using the name
  bPTFounded = False
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
          If pt.Name = istrPTName Then
              bPTFounded = True
              Exit For
          End If
      Next pt
      If bPTFounded Then Exit For
  Next ws

  ' If founded, calculate the maximum. If not found, result is undefined
  If bPTFounded Then
      Set myRange = pt.PivotFields(istrPTField).DataRange
      getMaxPT = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(myRange)
  End If
End Function

Sub getMaxPTTest()
    Dim x As Double

    x = getMaxPT("myPivotTable", "myPTColumnName")
End Sub
```